# Redirect domain with nodeJS + Express

Tags: node.js, express

I've got an existing live website, I want to change the domain but keep all the subpages the same.

for example: I want to redirect traffic from `oldwebsitedomain.co/about` to `newwebsitedomain.studio/about`

I'm using Angular Universal, and here is what I believe to be the relevant extract from the `server.ts`

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', {req, res}, (err, html) => {
        if (html) {
          res.send(html);
        } else {
          console.error(err);
          res.send(err);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have nginx or apache as reverse proxy?

Comment: I'm using AWS Lambda with API Gateway, so I'm not sure how I would set that up. I'm just looking to make the change in nodeJS using the server.ts

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work nicely

```
app.all(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
      var host = req.header("host");
      if (host.match(/\bnewdomain.com\b/i)) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.redirect(301, "https://www.newdomain.com"  + req.url);
      }
    });

    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', {req, res}, (err, html) => {
        if (html) {
          res.send(html);
        } else {
          console.error(err);
          res.send(err);
        }
      });
    });
```